# How to re-install io.appium.settings after uninstalling them (Appium Settings app is not running after 5000ms)

Tags: selenium, appium

I am facing the issue: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT when using appium.
I found a solution that is uninstall these things:

```
adb uninstall io.appium.settings 
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server 
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test 
adb uninstall io.appium.unlock
```

However, after uninstalling, I try to run my script again, but a message showed:

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Appium Settings app is not running after 5000ms

Please tell me how to re-install those packages again?

Answer (score 1):

Go this [link](https://unpkg.com/browse/io.appium.settings@3.2.1/apks/settings_apk-debug.apk)

Download the apk, then install it on your devices

Note: you can choose another version.